# Google API OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api

I am trying to build an ETL integration with google sheets. On the front end i was able to promt user to grant access to their drive and sheets but what i would like to do is to somehow be able to then later run a scheduled sync from cloud funtions in Firebase to access their sheets and sync the data to another endpoint. How can i use use the permissions grant to do this on the backend without having to authenticate again? I cannot find any articles about this on the web or in the gapi documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the `offline_access` scope in the authorization request, you should receive a refresh token from the authorization server, if the user grants you that permission.

With that refresh token, you can get a new access token from the authorization server, without the involvement of the user.

Note that the refresh token typically has an expiration date too.

Comment: Thanks m8! Apparently getting a refresh token client side is not possible as it’s handled automatically by the library, instead what I could do is call the requestOfflineAccess() method on the client which returns a code which in return can be used in a backend request to obtain a proper token for future use.

Comment: What you are referring to is the refresh flow: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-6.